# Latin characters on Mint - Alt key like Windows

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

How can I use Latin characters on Linux Mint? I've tried the `alt` key like on Windows but it doesn't work. I've searched and they say that `alt` doesn't work on Linux like on Windows.

I've tried other keys, but none seems to work.

Comment: Even on windows that alt-codes varies from code page to code page.. It's kinda silly to try to remember them. You should always use things like US-international, which generally makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to activate the compose key to use that. Go to the `keyboard preferences`, to the `Layouts` tab and click on the `Options...` button.

It will open a new pop up, there you'll have to search for the option `Position of the Compose Key` and there you have a list of keys that you can enable for that functionality like `alt`, `ctrl`, etc.

---

**Edit**

On Linux the shortcuts don't work like on Windows.

Imagine, if you want to type `á` you have to press `alt` + `'` + `a` (assuming that `alt` is the compose key).

Comment: Ok Ive done that, but the codes dont work. I cant make the characters

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a "Compose" key. This is in system settings > keyboard preferences > layouts > options
2. Set the "compose" key to whatever you want. You might NOT want to use ALT because it is usually useful for other stuff. I set it to the little menu key on the right side of my keyboard, but you could use a windows key or whatever.
3. To *use* the compose key, the sequence is this:

   - press the compose key
   - press some letter (for instance, try the E key)
   - press a modifier (for instance, try the ' key)
   - now you have just created a é character!

   Note that this is NOT all of those keys *at the same time* but in sequence. So to get the é character, or an ñ character, or whatever, I have tapped THREE different keys, one after another:  compose, then e, and then '

Or compose, and then n, and then ~

This confused me for a while because on my old OS, the way you did it was option-shift-[some key]. But on Linux, its Compose [release] and then some letter [release] and then another key.

Try it!

More info: http://straightedgelinux.ml/unix/compose/?dir=unix

Comment: Thank you. The first solution worked too. I choosed the 2 if i could